# Error:DFS Browser expects a DistributedFileSystem

Tags: windows, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

[image: Error message]

How do I resolve the error as shown in the image above?

> Error:DFS Browser expects a DistributedFileSystem

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows,please change the "localhost to 127.0.0.1.